# Firebase & Retrieving Elements

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to read x amount of elements from Firebase, but I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something...

DataSnapshot returns the correct child count, however when I try to loop through the children, the loop never executes.

Note: Code in Kotlin

```
fun list(count: Int, callback: ListCallback) {
    val playersRef = firebase.child("players")
    val queryRef = playersRef.orderByChild("rank").limitToFirst(count)
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(error: FirebaseError?) {
            Log.e("firebase", error!!.message)
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            val children = snapshot!!.children
            // This returns the correct child count...
            Log.i("firebase", children.count().toString())
            val list = ArrayList<Entry>()
            // However, this loop never executes
            children.forEach {
                val e = Entry()
                e.name = it.child("name").value as String
                e.rank = it.child("rank").value as Long
                e.wins = it.child("wins").value as Long
                e.losses = it.child("losses").value as Long
                Log.i("firebase", e.toString())
                list.add(e)
            }
            callback.onList(list)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
val firebase: Firebase = Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/34378547")

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    list(3)
    Thread.sleep(5000)
}

fun list(count: Int) {
    val playersRef = firebase.child("players")
    val queryRef = playersRef.orderByChild("rank").limitToFirst(count)
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(error: FirebaseError?) {
            println(error!!.message)
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            val children = snapshot!!.children
            // This returns the correct child count...
            println("count: "+snapshot.children.count().toString())
            children.forEach {
                println(it.toString())
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Output:

```
count: 2
DataSnapshot { key = -K6-Zs5P1FJLk4zSgNZn, value = {wins=13, name=fluxi, rank=1, losses=1} }
DataSnapshot { key = -K6-ZtdotHkkBzs5on9X, value = {wins=10, name=puf, rank=2, losses=42} }
```

### Update

In the comments there was some discussion about why `snapshot.children.count()` works, while `children.count()` doesn't. The problem is caused by two facts:

1. Firebase's `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` returns an `Iterable`, which can be iterated forward only (as is the contract of an `Iterable`).
2. The Kotlin `count()` loops over the `Iterable` to count its items.

So after Kotlin's `count()` is done, the `Iterable` is at the end of the sequence. The subsequent `for` loop has nothing to loop over anymore. In my snippet I call `snapshot.children` separately to get a separate iterator to get the count.

Knowing how Kotlin implements `count()` it is better to use Firebase's built-in `childrenCount`:

```
println("count: "+snapshot.childrenCount)
```

Comment: Thank you for testing! So the problem is the count()-call! If I replace the `children.count()` with `snapshot.children.count()`, the code works correctly... strange! If I had to guess it's somekind of iterator (caching?) issue?

Comment: @fluxi I'am not familiar with firebase but I guess the reason is that you can iterate over children only once (at second attempt you get none). The function `count` iterates over all elements for `Iterator` so I guess it is not so efficient as you consume the data twice. It is very common approach for databases and other storages, so the Firebase does the same as well

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: is that a "public" type firebase db which anyone can read/write?