# search data from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

please i am trying to search the all column that (dcountry ="France") as example, as illustrated in picture:
[image]

i try that code, but not work:

```
 MyFirebase.db.child("Developer").orderByChild("dcountry")
            .startAt("France")
            .endAt("France"+ "\ufbff")
            .addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
```

Comment: try `child("Developers")` not "Developer"

Comment: yes i write the correct(developers), the error just in this image>>>
thank you, but i don't need just all country, i need all data in column when country="france", i mean all data (dcountry, ddesc,dimage,dgender....etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MyFirebase.db.child("Developers").orderByChild("dcountry").equalTo("France").addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
```

which will give you all countries that are equal to france

Comment: thank you, but i don't need just all country, i need all data in column when country="france", i mean all data (dcountry, ddesc,dimage,dgender....etc)

Comment: Yes use the above query and inside ondatachange retrieve the other data

Comment: it is wooooork, thank you very much brother, from where can i found  the best  tutorial about query in firebase

Comment: @user4399890 just check the documentations and search here on stackoverflow, you will find everything, check this also https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: please this code is just return the one Column? but i need all column where (dountry= "France")? where is the problem

Comment: @user4399890 see this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378547/firebase-retrieving-elements

Comment: how can i do that please?

Comment: @user4399890 please check the link, it is the same but instead of the query there, use the query I provided to you here in the answer

Comment: i don't think that, i use as here:
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                        devData.clear()
                        val td = p0?.value as HashMap<*, *>? 
                         for(keys in td.keys){
                    val row = td[keys] as HashMap<*, *> 
                        devData.add(Developers(row["dimage"].toString(), row["dname"].toString(),
                                null, row["dcountry"].toString(), null,
                                row["dspic"].toString(), null,
                                null, null, row["did"].toString()))
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166942/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-user4399890).

Answer (score 0):

I have written query using kotlin. But it will help you

```
    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()  
        .child("Developers")  
        .orderByChild("dcountry")
        .equalTo("france")
        .limitToFirst(50)
```